# Python - Circumvent argparse nargs error

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program that works like this:

```
prog.py filename -r
```

Uses default default values given by me

```
prog.py filename -r 0 500 20
```

Uses `0, 500 and 20`

I've managed to achieve this using:

```
class RdistAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string=None):
        if not values:
            setattr(namespace,self.dest,[0, 1000, 50])
        else:
            setattr(namespace,self.dest,values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", "--rdist", action=RdistAction, nargs='*', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

But I want to be stubborn, as my original goal was to have nargs set to 3. But when I use nargs=3 in the above code, I get an error message stating that 3 arguments were expected.

I've googled around, and from the results my gut tells me that I have to add `def __init__` and modify something in that function. Is it possible to get the same results I get in the above code when `nargs='*'`, but with `nargs=3` instead?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you don't provide `-r` at all?

Comment: Your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42928410

Comment: @hpaulj my program works like this, you enter a filename, and then the flag of the function you want to run. When it's only -r, the rdist function is run with standard values. When you enter -r with values, the rdist function is run with those values. I though I could post this as a new question, as now my question is more regarding the custom action and the nargs error.

Answer (score 24):

If I change your `add_argument` line to have `nargs='3'`, I think I get the error you're taking about:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 12, in <module>
ValueError: length of metavar tuple does not match nargs
```

If I set `nargs=3` (without the quotes), then it works for me:

```
import argparse

class RdistAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self,parser,namespace,values,option_string=None):
      if not values:
        setattr(namespace,self.dest,[0, 1000, 50])
      else:
        setattr(namespace,self.dest,values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", "--rdist", action=RdistAction, nargs=3, type=int)
print parser.parse_args('-r 0 500 20'.split())
```

gives

```
Namespace(rdist=[0, 500, 20])
```

Is that what you're looking for?

The trick here is that if nargs isn't one of the special characters ('?', '*', '+', etc), then it needs to be an integer, not a string.

Note that [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#nargs) does point this out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you missunderstood my question a bit. See the comments above for clarity :)

Comment: This is a great catch

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in your previous question, simply omitting the `-r` puts the `default` in the args Namespace.  You don't have to do anything special.

`nargs='?'` has a third option, `const`.

Your custom action acts a bit like this, in that it assigns a custom value to the Namespace when `-r` was used without any strings.

Parsing goes roughly as:

- assign defaults to namespace
- loop through the inputs, processing positionals and options in order
- for each argument, call its `Action.__call__`
- the number of `values` passed depends on the `nargs` parameter

Your custom `RdistAction` has no control over the number of `values`, except via its `nargs` attribute.  `nargs=3` means exactly 3, `nargs='*'` means 'as many as you can give me' (i.e. 0 or to the end or to the next flag).

In `optparse` an Action is give all the remaining `argv` strings, and can consume as many as it wants.  But in `argparse`, the allocation is done at a higher level, and the Action uses what it's given.

I have explored in Python bug/issue expanding `nargs` to include `regex` like ranges, e.g. `[0,3]`.  But that requires changes to the core of the parser.

You still haven't explained why you need this bare `-r` option.

Comment: But the thing is, I don't want to omitt the -r to get the default values. This custom action now does that for me, except for the fact that I have to use nargs='*'. I was basically just curious as to if it was possible to achieve the same with nargs=3 and circumvent the nargs error. See explanation above as to why I need bare -r option.

Comment: I'm basically looking for:
    `if values < 3:
        set default values to .....
    else:
        use given values`

But this doesn't work when set in tha `__call__` function, that's why I though it might work if something similar is done in `__init__`. But as you state in your answer, do you mean that doing something like that would require changing the argparse module?

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue11354 is the bug/issue that explores generalizing the `nargs` to include ranges.  It's not a trivial patch.